# Next.Js app.render() doesnt work if I use getRequestHandler with Express Js app

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I am new to NextJs and I am having a lot of trouble in it. I am making an app based on NextJs and Express Js for Shopify App. My Requirement is I want to show the NextJs page **redeem** when someone hits the route **/iframe** like this

```
app.get('/iframe', (req, res) => {
    // res.send('Hello World!');
    const actualPage = '/redeem'
    const queryParams = { id: req.params.id } 
    nextapp.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
  });
```

This works perfectly fine. The page renders but the problem is that the CSS doesn't loads. I have used @zeit/next-CSS package but still, I get many errors. Some are regarding Mime Type. 
I checked the solution and they say that I have to use this

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })
```

But if I use this then I cannot render **redeem** Page when I hit the route **/iframe**

Can anyone Help me in this? Seems like I have to use both but both don't work with each other.

All I want is to render a NextJs page with CSS on hitting any express route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })
```

after

```
app.get('/iframe', (req, res) => {
    // res.send('Hello World!');
    const actualPage = '/redeem'
    const queryParams = { id: req.params.id } 
    nextapp.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
  });
```

like this

```
app.get('/iframe', (req, res) => {
    // res.send('Hello World!');
    const actualPage = '/redeem'
    const queryParams = { id: req.params.id } 
    nextapp.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
  });
/*
Some code here....................
*/
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })
```